# Solving given initial value problem using the method of Laplace Transforms $y''+y=f(t)$ where $y(0) = 0$ and $y'(0) = 1$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I have the problem asking me to solve the initial value problem using the method of Laplace Transforms given
$$ y''+y=f(t); \ \ \ \ \ y(0) = 0, y'(0)=1 $$
where
$$ f(t)=\begin{cases} 0,&  0<t<1 \\
 1,& 1< t < 2 \\
 0,&  2 < t 
\end{cases}
$$

I took the Laplace of both sides
$$ L(y'') + L(y)=L(f)$$
I didn't bother to include the 2 other parts of the right side of the equation since they are both multiplied by 0.

The result came out to be:
$$ (s^2Y(s)-(s)(0)-(1)) + Y(s) = \frac{e^{-s}-e^{-2s}}{s} $$
then
$$ Y(s)(s^2+1)= \frac{e^{-s}-e^{-2s}}{s}+1$$
then
$$ Y(s)= \frac{e^{-s}-e^{-2s}}{s(s^2+1)}+\frac{1}{s^2+1} $$

From here, I believe I need to take the inverse Laplace to get my final answer. While I know that the 2nd term will come out to be sin(t) once I take the inverse Laplace, I'm unsure of how to go about the first one. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do partial fractions: 
$$
\frac{e^{-s}-e^{-2s}}{s(s^2+1)}=\frac{e^{-s}-e^{-2s}}{s}-\frac{se^{-s}-se^{-2s}}{s^2+1}
=\frac{e^{-s}}s-\frac{e^{-2s}}{s}-\frac{se^{-s}}{s^2+1}+\frac{se^{-2s}}{s^2+1}.
$$
The inverse Laplace transform is then, with $H(t)$ the Heaviside function, 
$$\tag1
H(t-1)-H(t-2)-\cos(t-1)H(t-1)+\cos(t-2)H(t-2).
$$
Note that your  $f$ can be written as  $f(t)=H(t-1)-H(t-2)$.

Comment: Thanks! I had a feeling that I was going to have to do partial fractions, I just wasn't quite sure what my answer should look like.

Comment: With inverse Laplace transforms, you *always* have to do partial fractions ;)